# User can't schedule a job in SAS Management Console

Tags: sas, job-scheduling

I am an admin for SAS analytics app and one user couldn't schedule a SAS job through SAS Management Console. He gets an error box message says:
Connect to Scheduler error
Unable to make connection to the scheduling server

[image]

I have also added him to the required group for scheduling.
However, still he faces this issue

Comment: anyone can help?